# Are installation instructions correct content of 'tag info' wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I'm seeing an increasing number of 'tag info' wiki pages being edited to include installation instructions.

Originally these tag info pages contained a summary of the tag, describing what it relates to. A useful addition was the inclusion of links to source documentation, source files, downloads or other relevant information.

I don't agree with the inclusion of installation instructions as they are liable to change. See the pending change on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvcscaffolding/info for an example.

Comment: I'd say the installation instructions themselves definitely don't belong in a tag wiki, but I don't see anything wrong with linking to the official documentation on installing a programming tool.  I'm less excited about linking to someone's blog, but I don't know that topic well at all, so I don't know if that's the best source for that info or not.

Comment: Seems like the blag owner is the co-creator of said framework or something according to this line: "So, I’ve been working with Scott Hanselman lately on an enhanced new scaffolding package called MvcScaffolding"

Comment: @OldCheckmark Ok, that seems like a pretty decent source of information then.  :)